ConTeXt: First use and subsequent use of acronym
I am trying to use acronym in ConTeXt that differs between first-time use and subsequent use. First time use should be in full, e.g., USB (Universal Serial Bus), but subsequent use will simply be USB.
I am using an answer in question How to define acronyms in ConTeXt?. I need indexing, so the last answer fits my need.
\definesynonyms[acron][acronyms][\fullac] % Define acronyms as context synonyms

% Define a new macro
\def\ac#1{
  \ifcsname AcroUsed#1\endcsname
    % If the acro was already used, return the acronym
    \csname #1\endcsname
  \else
    % Otherwise, set as used, print full and acro
    \fullacro{#1} (\csname #1\endcsname)
    \expandafter\def\csname AcroUsed#1\endcsname{1}
  \fi
}

But, ConTeXt returns error.
I changed \fullacro{#1} (\csname #1\endcsname) to \fullac{#1} (\csname #1\endcsname) and it compiles. However, there is an extra space next to the closing parenthesis to the next word.
My MWE is below.
\definesynonyms[acron][acronyms][\fullac] % Define acronyms as context synonyms

\acron[usb]{USB}{Universal Serial Bus}
\acron[npv]{NPV}{Net Present Value}
\acron[roe]{ROE}{Return on Equity}

% Define a new macro
\def\ac#1{
  \ifcsname AcroUsed#1\endcsname
    % If the acro was already used, return the acronym
    \csname#1\endcsname
  \else
    % Otherwise, set as used, print full and acro
    \fullac{#1} (\csname#1\endcsname)
    \expandafter\def\csname AcroUsed#1\endcsname{1}
  \fi
}

\starttext

I am copying the calculation of the project's \ac{npv} and \ac{roe} from my \ac{usb}.

\stoptext

What should I do to remove that unnecessary space? Thanks.

What you're trying to achieve is already supported by ConTeXt with the last alternative for synonyms.
\definesynonyms
  [acronym]
  [acronyms]

\setupsynonyms
  [acronym]
  [alternative=last]

\acronym {USB} {Universal Serial Bus}
\acronym {NPV} {Net Present Value}
\acronym {ROE} {Return on Equity}

\starttext

I am copying the calculation of the project's \NPV\ and \ROE\ from my \USB.

I am copying the calculation of the project's \NPV\ and \ROE\ from my \USB.

\stoptext


Thanks. ConTeXt default is a way to go.

I tinkered and made a slight change to the macro as following.
\definesynonyms[acron][acronyms][\fullac] % Define acronyms as context synonyms

% Define a new macro
\def\ac#1{%
  \ifcsname AcroUsed#1\endcsname%
    \csname#1\endcsname%
  \else%
    \fullac{#1}~(\csname#1\endcsname)%
    \expandafter\def\csname AcroUsed#1\endcsname{1}%
  \fi%
}

Now the extra space is gone.

It's cleaner if you replace the \def line with \gletcsname AcroUsed#1\endcsname\relax, although it doesn't make any practical difference.
